# Sort items by name in template instead of controller

Tags: angularjs

[Here is my runable Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rnNwf8oyP0uDMRQWAgf0?p=preview)

I want to sort items by name. This is the bug, for the top one, "Please select a student name", it displays as an empty field.

```
<select ng-options="student as student.name for student in students | orderBy: sortNameExcludeTopOne"
        ng-model = "student">        
</select>




$scope.sortNameExcludeTopOne = function(student) {
        if (student.id === 0) {
          return -1;
        }
        return student.name;
      }
```

What I want:

- Now I sort items by its name by using a custom function in the controller, can we do sort items by its name in the template? instead of in controller?
- What UI I want for select is:
  "Please select a student name" -> "Bar" -> "Foo"

Update: I want the "Please select a student name" at the top of select

Comment: Do you only need the "Please select a student name" at the top of select, or you need that the rest of yout list be sorted by name?

Comment: I want "Please select a student name" at the top of select. The rest of students sorted by name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need push the item to array, you can put then direct in the view:

```
<select ng-options="student as student.name for student in students | orderBy: 'name'" ng-model = "student">
  <option value="">Please select a student name</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your solution works for me. Why <option value="-1">Please select a student name</option> is displaying empty field, instead of "Please select a student name"

Answer (score 0):

You want the options available to them sorted by the name:

```
<select ng-options="student as student.name for student in students | orderBy: 'name'" ng-model="student">        
</select>
```

That should sort the students by their 'name' property.

Edit:
If you want to add the extra option at the top, then, use your controller to sort the 'students' first:

```
students() {
  const studentList = someStudents();
  studentList.sort((a, b) => {
    if(a.name < b.name) return -1;
    if(a.name > b.name) return 1;
    return 0;
  });
  studentList.unshift({ new: option, goes: here });
}
```

Then you can sort it there, and insert one more option at the beginning with the option you want visible.

Incidentally you could use orderBy: 'name' still, assuming your options are based on 'value'; you'd have to have one more default entry with a numeric value like so:

```
<select ng-options="student as student.name for student in students | orderBy: 'name'"
  ng-model="student">
  <option value="-1">Please select a student name:</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I want the "Please select a student name" at the top of select. I cannot use orderBy: "name" since this will also sort "Please select a student name"

Comment: Updated the answer with two further options for you, but you should still be able to use orderBy

Comment: <option value="-1">Please select a student name:</option> will result in empty field, instead of "Please select a student name:". Do you know why? I used value="", then works.